# Authentication fails in HttpClient but OK in browser

Tags: java, httpclient, http-authentication

I'm using `HttpClient 4.0` to get some XML from the remote host. When I use URL such as https://user:pwd@www.somesite.com it works fine in the browser but fails in the HttpClient with this stacktrace (follows). Any suggestions? I'm using `SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER` while setting `ThreadSafeClientConnManager` to handle HTTPS requests

The code (partial):

```
final HttpGet get= new HttpGet(url);
final HttpResponse response = this.client.execute(get);
return new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(response);
```

Stacktrace:

```
01-05 22:34:03.783: ERROR/SearchResults(11565): 
    Failed to process request to URL: 
    https://user:pwd@www.somesite.com/products/foo/meta/xml_proper_encoding.jsp?version=1
01-05 22:34:03.783: ERROR/SearchResults(11565): 
    org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Unauthorized
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass `UsernamePasswordCredentials` like in [this example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/branches/4.0.x/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientAuthentication.java), not in the URL.